# jQuery tablesorter child elements th disable sorting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tablesorter

I have child elements in `th` that are popup windows.  When i click `.show_history` div to display the popup div `.show_history_ctn`, sorting for that column is triggered.  I have increased the z-index for `.show_history` to 9999 and still sorting is triggered.  I've also added stopPropagation to `.show_history` click event and still sorting occurs.

jQuery

```
$(".show_history").on("click",function(event) {
        $(this).siblings(".show_history_ctn").find("tr").show();
        event.stopPropagation();
        if($(this).hasClass("active")) {
            $(this).siblings(".show_history_ctn").slideUp();
            $(this).removeClass("active");
        } else {
            $(".show_history_ctn").hide();
            $(".show_history").removeClass("active");
            $(this).siblings(".show_history_ctn").slideDown();
            $(this).addClass("active");
        }
    });

$(".tablesorter").tablesorter();
```

html

```
<table class='tablesorter'><thead><tr><th><div class='show_history'>Show History</div><div class='show_history_ctn' style='display:none'>**content**</div></th><th></th></tr></thead></table>
```

How do i solve?  I need sorting on the column otherwise i'd just add `sorter:'false'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the click binding is removed by tablesorter since it rebuilds the table header. You can solve this using either of the following methods:

- Set the `headerTemplate` option to an empty string (`""`) - this prevents altering the header content and therefore doesn't break any bindings. Internally, it is using an `innerHTML` (this will likely be changed soon) to wrap the content because jQuery's wrap was extremely slow in older versions of IE.
- Bind the popup links inside the `initialized` callback ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/bbxxomhx/678/))

  ```
  $(function() {

    function bindLink() {
      $('.link').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
      });
    }

    $('table').tablesorter({
      theme: 'blue',
      initialized: bindLink
    });

  });
  ```

Update: Oops, I forgot to include the [`cssNoSort` class name](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#cssnosort) of "tablesorter-noSort" which needs to be added to the element you're clicking on. Demo link updated above.

```
<th>AlphaNumeric <a class="link tablesorter-noSort" href="https://google.com">test</a>
```

Comment: I tried the demo and the clicking the popup links still are ignored and the column is sorted.